# Elements disappear on scroll ionic ios only

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I’ve come across a strange bug I cannot solve.

When I navigate to tab 2, the page acts as expected. Then if I navigate back to the tab 1, then go back to tab 2, my elements now disapear on scroll. This happens on ios only, and it happens no matter what component I set as tab 2.

(these components work fine on tab one which eliminates the problem being the component)

I’m using a very typical tab layout that I will post below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HomeComponent } from '../../home/home-component/home.component';
import { FirebaseHomeComponent } from '../../firebase/firebase-home/firebase-home.component';



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsComponent {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root: any = HomeComponent;
  tab2Root: any = FirebaseHomeComponent;

  constructor() {

  }
}
HTML:

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="{{'HOME' | translate}}" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="{{'PROFILE' | translate}}" tabIcon="contact"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

Module:

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../../app/shared/shared.module';
import { TabsComponent } from './tabs-component/tabs.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TabsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TabsComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    TabsComponent
  ]
})
export class TabsModule {}

Ionic Framework: 3.2.0
Ionic app script: 3.0.0
Angular core: 4.1.0
angular compiler cli: 4.1.0
node: 8.9.0
```

Comment: Hey welcome to SO, can you make sure you share a code that can help reproduce the issue? you can use stackblitz service for that. Also did you try reproducing it on Ionic 3.9.2?

Comment: Stack blitz seems solid I'll mess with that and see about getting it posted. I'll also try and update, strange this is an ios only bug

Comment: Actually no stack blitz isn't likely to help. This issue doesn't occur on android or on browser, only on an ios production build and running through emulator or device.

Comment: I see - then you should try list your specific ios version. But without a reproducible configuration its hardly you can expect help here. But do check bug tracker for ios safari

Comment: may I know how much data you are showing on that screen and is it list type data ?

Comment: Yeah this behavior happens no matter what type of data or how much so long as there is enough to bring a scroll to the page. I can literally have one giant p tag or a bunch of p tags so long as it's big enough to cause a scroll then the elements will disappear on scroll once re navigated back to tab 2 (not the first time you navigate to page 2).

Comment: I've tried several different apps and templates and it always seems to happen on ios only regardless of versions or emulators/devices. It's almost like ionic doesn't like pages to be scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

The answer is to install this plugin. Fixed it like a charm. I was stuck on this for 15 days I could not find the solution anywhere so I hope it helps.